# FluentValidation - Apply prefix string message in front of child validator response

Tags: c#, fluentvalidation

AddressValidator

```
public class AddressValidator : AbstractValidator<Address>
    {
       public AddressValidator()
          {
            RuleFor(a => a.Name).NotEmpty().WithName("Name1");
          }
}
```

InputValidator

```
public class InputValidator : AbstractValidator<Input>
   {       
       public InputValidator()        
       {
           RuleFor(i => i.PickupAddress)
               .SetValidator(new AddressValidator())
               .WithName("Pickup");

           RuleFor(i => i.DropoffAddress)
               .SetValidator(new AddressValidator())
               .WithName("Dropoff");
       }
}
```

As you can see I am trying to use the same AddressValidator twise in my InputValidator. My goal is to set a Rule such that a string prefix "Pickup" or "Dropoff" is applied in front of each error response from the AddressValidator. As can be seen above I have tried setting .WithName after .SetValidator without succsess.

The end result I am looking for: "Pickup name1 is missing" or "Dropoff name1 is missing".

Can this be done somehow?

Comment: You could probably pass the prefix to the address validator constructor

Comment: Yes, that is the temporary solution I have implemented right now, but I was hoping to avoid passing strings in such a way.

Comment: Both `WithName` overloads are scoped to a property, not a child with it's own properties. `WithState` is the same, it doesn't pass to the child validator. A custom display name resolver is scoped to the validator, you don't have access to the parent. I'm out of other ideas.